# In formal writing, is it acceptable to repeat nouns as in the sentence below?

Tags: nouns, repetition

I am writing some journal papers. I need to be technical but at the same time I don't really want to repeat the same terminology over and over.

The sentence I am having trouble with is like this:

> Better discrimination between A and B results in better discrimination between B and C.

My questions are

1. Is it okay to repeat the noun 'discrimination' like the above?
2. If not, how should I rephrase it without losing technicality?

Please help.

Comment: For formal usage, it's spot on. And I can't imagine that there would be much need for informal usage.

Comment: I'd use *Better discrimination between A and B repeats **itself** between B and C*.

Comment: To my ear, @YosefBaskin's version has replaced clarity with vagueness.